# Diferenças entre definições de eventos

Tags: jquery

#### Exemplos

**1.**

```
<button onclick="clickTeste()">Teste</button>

function clickTeste() {
    alert("click");
}
```

**2. (a que vejo ser mais utilizada)**

```
$("#testeid").click(function() {
    alert("click");
});
```

**3.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click","#testeid",function() {
        alert("click");
    });
});
```

---

- Quais vantagens/desvantagens se tem em cada uma delas?
- Há mais formas de definição além dessas?

Comment: Sua pergunta diz respeito somente ao que é feito via jQuery? E tem algum motivo especial para o exemplo 3 ter document.ready e o 2 não ter?

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, seria específico para jQuery. Sobre o `document.ready`, pelo que andei lendo, tem relatos que usando o `.on` sem estar em `.ready`, houveram casos que não funcionaram. Por isso fiquei mais ainda na dúvida... Até então, acho que o 2o é o mais usado, pois elimina a necessidade de setar atributo no HTML, e o uso de `.ready`.

Comment: Marquei como duplicata porque tem um monte de pergunta sobre o assunto aqui. Seu exemplo 1 não tem jQuery, então os links não tratam dele (tem outras perguntas no site que tratam). Os 2 últimos links são sobre a questão do document.ready, que seria uma dúvida à parte.

Comment: @bfavaretto Obrigado, vou dar uma olhada!

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente os 3 métodos irão realizar a mesma ação. Usar JavaScript ou JQuery realmente depende das necessidades do projeto a ser desenvolvido.
Utilizar Jquery torna o processo de desenvolvimento mais ágil para ser finalizado. Se você precisa desenvolver algo em javascript que não possa demorar tanto para ser lançado, com certeza o jquery pode ser explorado. De qualquer modo, você estará utilizando ótimas tecnologias para desenvolvimento de suas aplicações.

Answer (score 0):

O chamando ele desta forma `.click(function(){})` você esta usando um **shortcut** para a chamada `.on('click',function(){})`.

Já chamando ele sem passar uma função, ou seja, desta forma `.click()` você esta fazendo um **shortcut** para a chamada `.trigger('click')`.

Esta é a forma de definir o evento através do HTML `<button onclick="clickTeste()">`

`.on(type,listener)` este método aceita alem do evento `click`,`change` e todos os outros evento do `html`, ele também aceita eventos customizados.

Exemplo: evento de abertura de modal do **bootstrap**, `.on('show.bs.modal',function(){})`

Existem ainda o

- `<HTMLElement>.onclick=function(){}`
- [`<HTMLElement>.addEventListener(type,listener[, options])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener)

`<HTMLElement>.onclick=function(){}` nesse você esta adicionando um evento ao elemento de forma direta, usando dessa forma você só vai conseguir manter um evento no elemento e para remover o evento é só colocar o valor para `null` ou uma função vazia.

`<HTMLElement>.addEventListener(type,listener[, options])` já esta forma é bem parecida com o jquery você pode colocar `n` eventos e para remover você tem que chamar o [`<HTMLElement>.removeEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). Eu acredito que o `jQuery.on`, `jQuery.off` faça uso desses eventos.

---

Posso esta errado mas não acho que haja uma vantagem/desvantagem entre `.click(function(){})` e `.on('click',function(){})` nesta forma, acho que é apenas uma questão de praticidade e padronização.

[`jquery.click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/), [`jquery.on( type [, selector ] [, data ], listener )`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Mas Icaro, qual a vantagem e desvantagem de cada? Mera "organização" do código? Por que a maioria que vejo, usa `.click(function(){})` e não utilizando o atributo no HTML? Ou pq, utilizar o `ready`? Me traria uma segurança que todo o documento foi carregado antes de executar qualquer ação!?
Gostaria de mais detalhes por favor... Mas agradeço a resposta! ✌️